# What is expected value of a random variable with density $\frac{1}{(1+y)^{2}}$ for $y > 0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

If $Y$ is a random variable with p.d.f.
\begin{align*}
f_{Y}(y) = \frac{1}{(1 + y)^{2}}
\end{align*}
for $y > 0$. How can I calculate expected value of this random variable?

Comment: Try to show your attempt.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you aware of the definition for the expected value?

Comment: Hi! yes, I know. when I plot this function, it seems that must have an expected value.

Comment: @Majid Could you please let us know what you tried so that we can better help you?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I calculated its integral, but it seems, has not any real answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\mathbb{E}Y = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot P(Y=y) dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} y \cdot f_Y(y) dy$$

Comment: Hi. How can we do this for 1/(y+1)^2? I Know how to calculate expected value for any RV but in this case, I can't solve it.

Comment: This is just a calculus II exercise. Try the substitution $z = y + 1$ and you should see the integral diverges in the end.

Comment: @SeanRoberson I think this is more than calculus II exercise. It goes to +inf but we know this RV is not going to +inf.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The integral is divergent in the end, so the random variable has undefined expectation - this is allowed (and this is a case of the Cauchy distribution, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

Comment: Thank you for your help! @SeanRoberson